# nonlinear equation problem

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

Can you please help me solve the following nonlinear equation to determine the value of the vector $z$ :
$$
\boldsymbol{a}=\boldsymbol{z}^{2} \odot \boldsymbol{K}*\boldsymbol{z}^{-1}$$
Where:

- $\boldsymbol{a}$ is a given vector with all positive entries.
- $K$ is an element-wise positive, symmetric, and positive semi-definite matrix.
- $\odot$ represents the element-wise product.
- the exponents represent elementwise exponentiation
- $*$ represents matrix multiplication.

Is there an approach or method to solve this equation?

The equation above can be written as follows for each element of vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$, $\boldsymbol{z}$, and matrix $\boldsymbol{K}$
$a_i=\sum_j z_i^2 K_{i j} z_j^{-1}$

Comment: When you ask, "Is there another approach...", that indicates that you already know (at least) one approach. Please tell us what approach(es) you already know, so we don't waste time and effort telling you things you already know.

Comment: I know some folks avoid indices at all costs, but this often makes it more difficult to understand what is intended. Do you mean: $a_i=\sum_{j,k} z_iz_jK_{jk}z_k^{-1}$? If not, please clarify.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, I removed the extra parameters.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I have tried solving it analytically but couldn't find a solution. I also attempted using Matlab's 'fsolve ' function but without success.

Comment: Then maybe you should remove the misleading word "another" from your post, Iman.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I would have thought it was $a_i = \sum_j z_i^2K_{ij}z_j^{-1}$, based on the description in the post.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, Yes, you are right.

Comment: @ImanNodozi I suggest editing the question to use the equation in my comment and dispense with the (to me) novel notation for the operations. Everyone here would be comfortable with index notation.

Comment: Ah, I see, the interpretation by David Roberts makes sense, I guess -- and I agree it would be better to use that in the question (assuming it is indeed what Iman intended to ask? If not, all the more reason to clarify the question)

Comment: Do you want a solution $z$ with positive coefficients?

Comment: @DavidRoberts, I added your equation to the main question.

Comment: @PietroMajer, yes.

Comment: This is equivalent to $a_i x_i^2 =\sum_j K_{ij} x_j$, for $x_i=z_i^{-1}$, it seems.

Comment: And one may also absorb the coefficients $a_i$, letting $y_i:=a_i^{1/3}x_i$ and  $K'_{ij}:=a_i^{-1/3}K_{ij}a_j^{-1/3}$, still a symmetric semi-definite matrix with non-negative coefficients. The equation then writes $y_i^2=\sum_j K'_{ij}y_j$.

Comment: Never mind, Iman, I did it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an existence argument on the lines of the proof of the Perron-Frobenius theorem via the Brouwer fixed point theorem.
Note that from the equation, since by assumption $a_i>0$ and $K_{ji}\ge0$,  it follows that a necessary condition for existence of a solution $z\in\mathbb R^n$ with $z_i>0$ is **(1):** $\sum_jK_{ij}>0$ for all $i$ .

To show this is also sufficient, note that may also assume w.l.o.g that **(2):** $K$ is not a direct sum of smaller blocks (up to reordering of the indices). Otherwise, the system would break in a direct sum of smaller systems of the same kind. Equivalently: some power of $K$ has all coefficients non-zero.

Let $\Delta:=\{u\in\mathbb R^n:u_i\ge0,\sum_j u_j=1\}$. For any $u\in\Delta$ put $v_i:=a_i^{-1}\sum_jK_{ij}u_j^{1/2}$. Note that  for any $u\in\Delta$ one has $u_j>0$ for least one index $j$, so that it follows by **(1)** that $\lambda:=\sum_iv_i\ge (\max_i a_i)^{-1}(\sum_i K_{ij_{0}})u_{j_{0}}^{1/2}>0$ (recall $K_{ij}=K_{ji}$). Consider the map $\Delta\ni u\mapsto \frac{v}{\lambda}\in\Delta.$ By the  Brouwer fixed point theorem this map has a fixed point $u\in\Delta$, thus verifying for some $\lambda>0$
$$\lambda u_i=a_i^{-1}\sum_jK_{ij}u_j^{1/2}.$$ By assumption **(2)** this implies that $u_j>0$ for all $j$.
Therefore $z_i:= \lambda^{-2} u_i^{-1}>0$ solves
$$ a_i=z_i^2\sum_j K_{ij}z_j^{-1}.$$